# How do I generate public and private keys with pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I can obtain the private key (PEM format), but I'm not sure how to generate the public key:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL

key = crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)
priv_key = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)
pub_key = ... ?
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the pyopenssl docs

`pub_key = crypto.dump_publickey(type, key)`

where type = The file type (one of :data:`FILETYPE_PEM` or    :data:`FILETYPE_ASN1`).

Hope this helps